# Issue when generating PDF with wkhtmltopdf, doc dimensions shrinked

Tags: pdf

Output PDF doc gets shrinked to an unpredictable size.

I'm having this issue when generating PDFs docs with wkhtmltopdf.

I've already tried chaining the flag --disable-smart-shrinking and setting options to no success.

We are also using this virtual monitor: xvbf

I generated the same documents from a local installation chaining --disable-smart-shrinking and setting options and got the expected results. The docs were generated correctly.

The options don't seem to be read when including them in the command line provided to the Civi system.

Can anyone help?